# url formatting using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have xxx.com and six input fields in a page. If user enter values in the input field I want the URL to be like `xxx.com/1st value-2nd value-3rd value-etc`

Now I am getting the input values in jQuery and passing those values to the URL but I could pass a single value and not all. Here's my code.

```
$(".search").on("click",function(e){
    // var action = $(this).attr("id");
    var skill = $(":input[name='searchskill']").val();
    var location = $("#searchlocation").val();
    action = skill + "-" + location;
    location.href = action;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `'/'` instead of `'-'` and get the url parameters in php function like

```
 function($skill='',$location=''){

 }
```

and now script will be like

```
 $(".search").on("click",function(e){ 
    var skill = $(":input[name='searchskill']").val();
    var location = $("#searchlocation").val();
    action = skill + "/" + location;
    location.href = action;
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$(".search").on("click",function(e){
    // var action = $(this).attr("id");
    var skill = $(":input[name='searchskill']").val();
    var location = $("#searchlocation").val();
    action = skill + "/" + location;
    window.location.href = action;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT**
Now I have created plunker for you please edit or suggest what you not getting in it, you also edit that plunker and give me new link to it 
here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k4kn7vru/)

Comment: Please make sure your jquery actually fetching values by alerting them before passing

Comment: @M.Athishkrishna I tried this code running locally, I am sure you are making mistake anywhere in your actual code. Please check once again and if possible provide your actual code